# Serve private mapping from S3 tiles by proxying data or signing urls through heroku?

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, mapping, leaflet, cesiumjs

I want to store mapping tiles in a private S3 bucket. Each tile has its own URL and each set of tiles could potentially have GBs of tiles.

I then want to visualise these tiles through a front end mapping client (e.g leaflet). This client pulls tiles as it needs them using the tile's individual URL.

Because the bucket is private I need to authenticate each tile request but performance is fairly critical for this application.

Given that I want to use heroku to host my site, is it better to proxy the url through heroku and get it signed before requesting the tile from S3 or proxy the tile itself through heroku?

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content in S3 is private, you are going to have to authorize the download one way or another, unless the bucket policy allows the proxy to access the content without authentication based on its IP address.  Even then, the proxy still needs to verify that the user is authorized via (presumably) a cookie, which might mean a session database lookup.

Generating a signed URL is not a particularly expensive process, computationally, and (contrary to the impression I occasionally encounter) the signing process is done entirely on your server -- there's no actual interaction with S3 that occurs when generating a signed URL.

There's not really a single correct answer.  I use both approaches, and a combination of them -- signing URLs in the application, signing them in the database (I have written a MySQL stored function that signs URLs), providing a link to a different app server that reads the user's session cookie and, if authorized, generates a signed URL and returns a 302 redirect, providing a link to a proxy server that proxies pre-signed URL requests to S3 (for real-time logging and to allow me to use my own domain name and SSL cert)... there are valid use cases for all of these approaches, and others.

Comment: Great suggestion about redirecting, I'm going to go with that. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help.  Note that for one-time downloads (as would be the case with redirects) you can set the expiration time very short, just a few seconds, if desired for security reasons.  As long as the URL doesn't expire before S3 *starts* the download, you're fine -- if the download takes a few seconds and the link expires after the download starts but before it ends because the file is large or the user's connection is slow, that is fine: S3 won't kill the download in the middle, because the link was valid at the time it was presented to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I think you want to proxy the requests through a server that is authorized to access the S3 bucket to minimize authentication transactions.

Whether it's on Heroku or not, as long as the proxy server is able to authenticate the end user's access and maintain that session according to the required security policies you should be fine.

Cesium does support Proxies for Imagery and Terrain so once that is in place you should just have to configure the CesiumProxy with your server and be good to go.